How to unit test oversized files between multer and s3 with the v3 sdk?
I'm trying to test different scenarios for file uploads. Obviously, I don't want to actually upload to s3 so I'm mocking that using aws-sdk-client-mock. The scenario that I'm stuck on is testing the upload of a file that is too large (defined by the fileSize limits configuration in multer). When the s3Client is mocked and the file is at or greater than the limit size, the test will hang. Without the mock everything works as expected. There should be some function that I can mock to make this work as expected.
Note that I'm using the AWS V3 SDK @aws-sdk/client-s3
With the S3 mock, the test is failing Error: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const multer = require('multer')
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3')

const upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: new S3Client({ region: 'AWS_REGION'}),
    bucket: 'BUCKET_NAME',
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 } // 5 MB limit
})

app.post('/upload',
  (req, res) => {
    const uploadSingle = upload.single('file')
    uploadSingle(req, res, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err.message) 
      }
      res.send({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        file: req.file
      })
    })
  }
)

module.exports = app

// upload.test.js
const request = require('supertest')
const { S3Client }  = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const { mockClient } = require('aws-sdk-client-mock')
const app = require('./app')

const s3Mock = mockClient(S3Client) // <-- Mocking hangs test

describe('File upload', () => {
  it('should reject oversized files', async () => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/upload')
      .attach('file', Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 10), 'test-big-file.png') // Limit 5MB
  
    expect(res.status).toBe(400)
    expect(res.text).toContain('File too large')
  })
})


Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Show the code under test and the errors
